# Get PATH environment variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, path, ellipsis

I want to check the PATH environment variable in PowerShell

I've tried

```
Get-ChildItem env:path
```

I want to get the complete path, but get only a very small part of it. How much I get depends on the width of the PowerShell window, e.g.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Progra...
```

Comment: ``$env:Path -replace ';', "`n"``

Comment: `$env:Path` alone will expand the list so you can read it all.  However, the replacement with CrLf is very nice.

Comment: Please consider selecting one of the answers as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 18):

If want to see the full path, one method is to use `echo`:

```
echo $env:path
```

Comment: actually, there is no need for echo, you can just use `:\>$env:path`

Answer (score 7):

If its just a display issue, you can pipe it to the `Format-List` cmdlet:

```
get-childitem env:path | Format-List *
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's just a display issue you can also use `Select-Object`

```
Get-ChildItem Env:\Path | Select-Object *
```

or get the property directly

```
(Get-ChildItem Env:\Path).Value
```

Running `$env:PATH` also works and will print the whole string value in case you don't need other properties, but if you want to print items in their own lines you can use

```
$env:Path -split ';'
```

or `` $env:Path -replace ';', "`n" ``

Some other alternatives being `$env:PATH.Split(';')` and `` $env:PATH.Replace(';', "`n") ``